# Loading a UIKit storyboard into Flutter with UiKitView has unresponsive buttons

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, uikit

I am following Flutters documentation almost exactly that they put together [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/ios/platform-views?tab=ios-platform-views-swift-tab).

The difference is I am trying to load in a storyboard with a view controller (I know next to nothing about native IOS Development). I will be creating a pretty basic screen that taps into some native features and would like to use a storyboard to create the UI.

You can see the storyboard here with the view controller and button. When I run this in flutter I get the "view loaded: optional button stuff" print to console so I know that the button is not null. However tapping the button does not call the buttonPressed method. I held control and drug it into my controller and am pretty sure it is connected correctly. The view also has enabled user interactions. I am lost on what I may be doing wrong to allow the interaction here.

[image]

```
init(
    frame: CGRect,
    viewIdentifier viewId: Int64,
    arguments args: Any?,
    binaryMessenger messenger: FlutterBinaryMessenger?
) {
    _view = UIView()
    super.init()
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "playground", bundle: Bundle.init(for: PlaygroundViewController.self))
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "playground") as! PlaygroundViewController
    _view = controller.view
}
```